# PHP - Export query to CSV wrong character on date field

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to create a CSV file from a mysql query, but i have problem with dates. I need to force enclose each fields with double quotes, and i'm using this function:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

$result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query) or die( mysqli_error( $db_conn ) );

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //fputcsv($fp, $row);
        fputcsv($fp, array_map(function($value) {
            if ($value == null || $value == "" || !isset($value) || $value === "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
                return '""';
            }

            ///remove any ESCAPED double quotes within string.
            $value = str_replace('\\"','"',$value);
            //then force escape these same double quotes And Any UNESCAPED Ones.
            $value = str_replace('"','\"',$value);
            // remove \n
            $value = str_replace("\n", '', $value);
            $value = str_replace("\r", '', $value);
            $value = str_replace("\r\n", '', $value);
            //force wrap value in quotes and return
            return "\"$value\"";
        }, $row), ',', chr(0));
    }

fclose($fp);
```

The export works for all (i think...) fields except from date field. Whe  i try to read the file in this way:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, null, ",", '"', '"')) !== false) {
  // Do someting
}
```

All fields are double quoted but, the dates field have this content:

```
"\x00"2008-12-31 10:08:43"\x00"
```

I tried many ways to solve this but.. without any result..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and figured out that single space character can crash CSV. Go through [this](http://www.alunr.com/excel-csv-import-returns-an-sylk-file-format-error/) link maybe it will help you to figure out your problem.